# Java 7's fork/join framework does not use all available CPU power

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, java-7, fork-join

I'm using [Java's fork-join framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html) to deal with a CPU- intensive calculation.

I've tweaked the "sequential threshold" (used to determine whether to create subtasks or do the work) a bit, but to my disappointment, going from single-threaded to 4+4 cores only about doubles the overall performance. The pool does report 8 CPUs, and when I manually set 2,3,4,.. I see gradual increases in performance, but still it tops out at about twice the single- thread throughput overall. Also, the Linux System Activity monitor hovers around 50% for that Java process.

Also very suspicious is the fact that when I start multiple Java processes, the collective throughput is more in line (almost 4 times faster than a single thread) and the System Activity monitor shows higher CPU use.

Is is possible that there is a limitation in either Java, Linux, or the fork/join framework that would disallow full CPU usage? Any suggestions or similar experiences?

NB. This is on an Intel 3770 CPU, with 4 cores and 4 hyperthreaded cores, running Oracle Java 7r13 on a Linux Mint box.

Comment: To understand what's happening on your fork-join setup, you need to figure out where the bottleneck is. Beyond that, it's really hard for us to make specific suggestions based just on the information in your question.

Comment: Interesting situation. Regarding the paralelization speedup, this is the theoretical limit: [Amdahl's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl's_law)

Comment: Also, you can't count on hyperthreaded cores as you can on the "real" cores, e.g.: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680684/multi-cpu-multi-core-and-hyper-thread) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360307/multicore-hyperthreading-how-are-threads-distributed). But the first thing I'd do is to follow NPE's advice

Comment: looks like a lot of blocking system calls that put the threads on wait, thereby lowering the CPU load reported by the kernel

Comment: try increasing parallelism in pool even higher, 16, 32, see what's happening.

Comment: @Ray you should look around for already written performance tests for FJ.  Run it on your machine and if you see 100% utilization on your computer there is a good chance it is your code.

Comment: Post a little code. what does your compute() look like. Just a little code, not every step.

Comment: Keep in mind that it is relatively easy to saturate all available memory bandwidth using a single CPU on some applications.  This may or may not be your bottleneck, but more threads rarely equates to a straightforward linear speedup.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the thoughts and answers, everyone! From your suggestions, I concluded that the problem was not the framework itself and went on to some more testing, finding that after a few minutes the cpu load dropped down to 15% !

Turns out, Random (which I use extensively) has poor performance in a multithreaded setup. The solution was to use ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextXXX() instead. I'm now up to consistent 80% usage (there are still some sequential passages left). Sweet!

Thanks again for putting me on the right track.